# Crossing a slightly longer box in Bernoulli percolation

Tags: pr.probability, percolation

Consdier critical Bernoulli bond percolation on $\mathbb{Z}^2$. Given $a, b \in \mathbb{N}$  denote by $p(a,b)$ the probability that there is an open left-right crossing in the box $[0,a]\times [0,b]$.

Standard Russo-Seymour-Welsh estimates show that $p(a,b)$ is bounded away from 0 and 1 by a constant depending only on the aspect ratio $b/a$ of the rectangle.

Now, given an aspect ratio $\lambda$ and some fixed $k > 0$, I would like to know if there is anything we can say about the asymptotics of the quantity $$p(n,\lambda n) - p(n,\lambda n + k)$$ as we let $n \rightarrow \infty$. This is the probability that there is a horizontal open crossing in $[0, \lambda n] \times [0, n]$ but where no crossing extends to length $\lambda n + k$. In particular, does this tend to 0?

My intuition leads me to believe that the difference does tend to 0. If we are instead working with site percolation on the triangular lattice, then these two domains are equal in the scaling limit and hence so should their crossing probabilities. However I am having trouble making this notion rigorous and would like an 'elementary' proof using only percolation theory.